# Pass single character to gcc as definition

Tags: gcc, compilation

I have version.c file with following line:

```
const uint8_t ID_SoftwareId[]   = { 'A', 'B', '0', '1', '0', '\0'};
```

I want to pass the `A` and `B` into this file through a definition.
I tired [few](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/443326-portable-way-pass-string-c-macro) [thigs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410976/how-to-define-a-string-in-gcc-command-line) but I usually end up with `Too many initializers` warning from gcc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
const uint8_t ID_SoftwareId[]   = { DEFA, 'B', '0', '1', '0', '\0'};
```

Then:

```
gcc -DDEFA=\'A\' ...
```

WorksForMe<sup>TM</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept:

```
#define TOKENIZE(x) #x
#define SINGLECHAR(x) (*(TOKENIZE(x)))

int main()
{
    char c = SINGLECHAR(DEFINITION);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and run:

```
cpp -DDEFINTION=Q test.c
```

Output

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"



int main()
{
 char c = (*("Q"));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is embedded application with no sdtlib so this is not an option.

Comment: Ok, I edited it to make it even more clear that my solution (of course) uses nothing than the preprocessor (cpp)