# configure use: how to write CFLAGS definition with a string define

Tags: linux, gcc, configure

I'm trying to compile fontconfig and redefine the value FONTCONFIG_FILE allowing to change the fonts.conf path.
It is possible by defining the CFLAGS with -DFONTCONFIG_FILE, but i dont find the correct way to write it.
Indeed i tried many combination, but none of them works.
CFLAGS= -DFONTCONFIG_FILE='"/path_to/fonts.conf"', i tried by adding '\' before each quotes but nothing works i never get:
gcc -DFONTCONFIG_FILE='"/path_to/fonts.conf"'

Can someone help on how i can give this define in the CFLAGS to be handled and used by the compiler?
BR.

Comment: Perhaps you should **add** to `CFLAGS` - `CFLAGS += -DFONTCONFIG_FILE=\"/path/to/fonts.conf\"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to define a string in gcc command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410976/how-to-define-a-string-in-gcc-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I'm giving CFLAGS in shell as i call configure with CFLAGS env var. It seems that fontconfig honors user CFLAGS seen that i can see the cflags later on. But I can not get the correctt syntax, as i understood,  -DFONTCONFIG_FILE='"/path_to/fonts.conf"'. In the file src/fccfg.c line 1796, you can see that we can set this define to be used in the c function. The best I succeed to get is  -DFONTCONFIG_FILE='/pathto/fonts.conf' with CFLAGS+=-DFONTCONFIG_FILE="'"/pathto/fonts.conf"'"