# How to #define and use expression in clang CFLAGS (string literal)

Tags: objective-c, clang

I'm trying to define string literal `Name` in command line and use it in my code, for example `NSLog("%@", Name);`. I'm referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410976/how-to-define-a-string-literal-in-gcc-command-line) and trying to convert it to clang/objective-c format.

In my makefile:

```
clang -DName=$(printf "%s-%d" $(ls $(PWD)/.folderA/folderB | sort -V | tail -n 1) $(cat $(PWD)/folderA/folderB/$(ls $(PWD)/.folderA/folderB | sort -V | tail -n 1)))
```

and in my code:

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE_VALUE_OF(x) STRINGIZE(x)
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:STRINGIZE_VALUE_OF(Name)]);
```

However, the logged output is empty. But if I try much more simpler command like

```
clang -DName=$(PWD)
```

it does logged correctly. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi - that should work. Just note, since that is a C string, you can log it directly using ```NSLog( @"%s", ...```) in stead of converting it and logging it with ```NSLog( @"%@", ...```. But that should work, I think the problem lies inside the ```$(printf ...```.

Comment: Looking at the inside, I think you have a ```.folder``` that should be just ```folder```.

Comment: `.folder` is a hidden folder, that's why its prefixed by `.`

Comment: Ok sure, still I think the trouble is there somewhere.