# Adding string Define at compilation time

Tags: c, makefile

Im trying to pass my git commit hash into my C program but im keep getting errors.

this is part of my makefile:

```
GIT_COMMIT := $(shell git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
Defines += -DGIT_COMMIT=\"$(GIT_COMMIT)\"\
```

and then I'm passing "Defines" to icc compiler.

in my C code , the following line causes error - "error: extra text after expected end of number"

```
printf("GIT COMMIT HASH: %s", GIT_COMMIT);
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why the extra backslash in the end?

Comment: not really needed here, but it also does not work without it.

Comment: Please post a full error message. You can also try hardcoding GIT_COMMIT in the makefile to isolate the error. Also `echo` the resulting `Defines` to see if something is wrong. Looking at the commands generated would also help.

Comment: This is the entire error the compiler gives.
i tried  to compile with  - DGIT_COMMIT=\"ABCDEFG"\" and now im getting - "error: identifier "ABCDEFG" is undefined", seems like it emits the ""

Comment: Not sure if it is makefile or shell issue, but you can probably add `#define STR(x) #x`  to your code and use `STR(GIT_COMMIT)` instead.

Comment: In fact there is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410976/how-to-define-a-string-literal-in-gcc-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Defines += -DGIT_COMMIT=\"$(GIT_COMMIT)\"
```

instead of

```
Defines += -DGIT_COMMIT=\"$(GIT_COMMIT)\"\
```

Always prefer to [stringify](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html) when passing strings to the preprocessor, otherwise passing values with `#` at the begining or containing quotes will fail, you can use something like:

```
#define GET_GIT_COMMIT_(x) #x
#define GET_GIT_COMMIT(x) GET_GIT_COMMIT_(x)

printf("GIT COMMIT HASH: %s", GET_GIT_COMMIT(GIT_COMMIT));
```

Then, in the Makefile:

```
Defines += -DGIT_COMMIT="$(GIT_COMMIT)"
```

Comment: now it compiles but it prints - :"GIT COMMIT HASH: GIT_COMMIT", it does not recognize it as define

Comment: Which form are you using? `"\"$(GIT_COMMIT)\\"` or `"$(GIT_COMMIT)"`? you only need to stringify in the second case, `"\"$(GIT_COMMIT)\\"` is already stringified.

Comment: it didnt work with - "$(GIT_COMMIT)"
and with - "\"$(GIT_COMMIT)\\" there was a makefile error.
i managed to do it with - \"$(GIT_COMMIT)\"

thanks for the help!

Comment: It works fine, at least on `gcc`: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81e34f559e8fafe4

Comment: Ah, ok, it was already expanded in a variable in the Makefile, I didn't pay atention to that :)