# How to concatenate two wide strings using a macro in C?

Tags: c, macros

I want to concatenate two wide strings using a macro, so I define some macros:

```
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 1
#define VERSION_BUILD 0
#define VERSION_REVISION 0


#define _STR(s) #s
#define STR(s) _STR(s)

#define _TOWSTRING(x) L##x
#define TOWSTRING(x) _TOWSTRING(x)


//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string
#define PRODUCT_ELASTOS_VERSION STR(VERSION_MAJOR) "." \
                                STR(VERSION_MINOR) "." \
                                STR(VERSION_BUILD) "." \
                                STR(VERSION_REVISION)
```

now I want to define a new macro PRODUCT_ELASTOS_VERSION_W using macro PRODUCT_ELASTOS_VERSION, it's value should be  L"1.1.0.0". so how can I define this macro?
TOWSTRING(PRODUCT_ELASTOS_VERSION) is wrong answer.

And if I want to concatenating string, how should I write? 
L"v" TOWSTRING(PRODUCT_ELASTOS_VERSION) cann't get wide string L"v1.1.0.0".

Comment: Note that `_` followed by UPPER-CASE letter at the beginning of an identifier is a reserved word (could be c++ only though, I'm not sure). You can put the `_` at the end instead, like `STR_` and `TOWSTRING_`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't REVISION come after BUILD? And about keeping build counts, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713459/how-do-you-track-the-build-count-of-your-library-when-there-are-multiple-authors) maybe it could be useful (or you may have a better idea!)

Answer (score 0):

First, `PRODUCT_ELASTOS_VERSION` does not expand to "1.1.0.0", it expands to

```
"1" "." "1" "." "0" "." "0"
```

Keeping the same structure you can define another identifier that expands to

```
L"1" L"." L"1" L"." L"0" L"." L"0"
```

with

```
#define _LSTR(s) L ## #s
#define LSTR(s) _LSTR(s)

#define ANOTHER_IDENTIFIER LSTR(VERSION_MAJOR) L"." \
                           LSTR(VERSION_MINOR) L"." \
                           LSTR(VERSION_BUILD) L"." \
                           LSTR(VERSION_REVISION)
```

Comment: It's not the best way, because if I define PRODUCT_NAME "hello wold", then wprintf(L"%s\n", L"v" TOWSTRING(PRODUCT_NAME)) works ok, but wprintf(L"%s\n", TOWSTRING(PRODUCT_VERSION)) is wrong.I want that each macro can works in the same way.