# Concatenate int to string using C Preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'm trying to figure out how I can concatenate a `#define`'d int to a `#define`'d string using the **C** Preprocessor.  My compiler is GCC 4.1 on CentOS 5.  The solution should also work for MinGW.

I'd like to append a version number onto a string, but the only way I can get it to work is to make a copy of the version number defines as strings.

The closest thing I could find was a method of quoting macro arguments, but it doesn't work for `#define`s

This is does not work.

```
#define MAJOR_VER 2
#define MINOR_VER 6
#define MY_FILE "/home/user/.myapp" #MAJOR_VER #MINOR_VER
```

It doesn't work without the `#`s either because the values are numbers and it would expand to `"/home/user/.myapp" 2 6`, which isn't valid **C**.

This does work, but I don't like having copies of the version defines because I do need them as numbers as well.

```
#define MAJOR_VER 2
#define MINOR_VER 6
#define MAJOR_VER_STR "2"
#define MINOR_VER_STR "6"
#define MY_FILE "/home/user/.myapp" MAJOR_VER_STRING MINOR_VER_STRING
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a preprocessor token to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Classical C preprocessor question....

```
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define MAJOR_VER 2
#define MINOR_VER 6
#define MY_FILE "/home/user/.myapp" STR(MAJOR_VER) STR(MINOR_VER)
```

The extra level of indirection will allow the preprocessor to expand the macros before they are converted to strings.

Comment: STR() in this case will give a Narrow string. Is there a variation to convert this to a wide string?

Comment: I couldn't say how many times I googled it and copied from this exact answer, but it's going to be in double digits

Comment: The first "STR_HELPER" is required because '#' only works with a macro argument. It took me sometime to figure that out..

Comment: @clarkttfu, sort of -- yes, `#` only works with macro arguments. However, the `STR_HELPER` macro is needed to avoid turning the macro `MAJOR_VER` into the string `"MAJOR_VAR"`, wheres we want to the result to be `"2"`.

Comment: My brain hurts that this can't be done with a single macro...
As a lot of other people, used this dozens of times

Answer (score 16):

A working way is to write MY_FILE as a parametric macro:

```
#define MY_FILE(x,y) "/home..." #x #y
```

EDIT: As noted by "Lindydancer", this solution doesn't expand macros in arguments. A more general solution is using two-step macros:

```
#define MY_FILE_(x,y) "/home..." #x #y
#define MY_FILE(x,y) MY_FILE_(x,y)
```

Comment: It's a clean solution which, unfortunately, doesn't work. If the argument passed to `MY_FILE` are macros, say `A` and `B`, this macro will expand to `"/home..." "A" "B"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/stringize.html):

```
#define MAJOR_VER 2
#define MINOR_VER 6
#define MY_FILE "/home/user/.myapp" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(MAJOR_VER) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(MINOR_VER)
```

Comment: Makes me smirk how people throw Boost at everything.

Comment: @Frerich: Taking your argument to extreme, people should write their own compilers first in raw machine code, rather than throwing g++ at everything... No point to reinvent the wheel. Good programmers write code, great ones reuse.

Comment: @jonescb: just open [the boost header](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp) and see for yourself.

Comment: Yep, I tried it.  It did work, but using a Boost header in a C program seems kind of odd to me.

Comment: Oh, my bad, did not notice `C` tag.