# How to append two #define together as keywords in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to do something like:

```
#define TYPE uint32_t
#define ADDSUFFIX(x) xTHETYPE

THETYPE * ADDSUFFIX(getvalue) (THETYPE * pMem) {}
```

And I need to get `uint32_t getvalueuint32_t (uint32_t * pMem) {}` depends on what TYPE is.

How to make this work ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459868/c-preprocessor-concatenate-int-to-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the "token pasting" operator, but it can get tricky when one of the operands is a parameter or a macro. This worked for me:

```
#define THETYPE uint32_t
#define ADDSUFFIX_2(x,y) x ## y
#define ADDSUFFIX_1(x,y) ADDSUFFIX_2(x,y)
#define ADDSUFFIX(x) ADDSUFFIX_1(x,THETYPE)

THETYPE * ADDSUFFIX(getvalue) (THETYPE * pMem) {}
```

If you want getvalue_uint32_t, this works:

```
#define ADDSUFFIX(x) ADDSUFFIX_1(x ## _,THETYPE)
```

Also consider:

```
#define MKFUNC(type,func,param) \
type * ADDSUFFIX_1(func ## _,type) (type * param)
MKFUNC(uint32_t,getvalue,pMem) { }
```

Comment: It seems a common problem. I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macro

Comment: I want to use `gcc -D U32 -c x.c -o x32.o` and  `gcc -D U64 -c x.c -o x64.o`. And I think this should be a way of implying template functions in C.