# Stringifying with leading zeros

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor

I'm looking for a way to have a fixed length Device name in C++ at compile-time, as string literal.

For example :

```
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define VERSION 6
#define DEVICE_NAME "MyDevice" STR(VERSION)
```

A fixed length with leading zeros to fit 4 digits is my desired output, Just like as `"MyDevice0006"`, The actual output using previous code is `"MyDevice6"`.

I've searched and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28579877/9168874) :

```
#undef VER
#define VER ...your version number...

#undef SMARTVER_HELPER_
#undef RESVER
#if VER < 10
#define SMARTVER_HELPER_(x) 000 ## x
#elif VER < 100
#define SMARTVER_HELPER_(x) 00 ## x
#elif VER < 1000
#define SMARTVER_HELPER_(x) 0 ## x
#else
#define SMARTVER_HELPER_(x) x
#endif
#define RESVER(x) SMARTVER_HELPER_(x)
```

But Trying it gives me the error :

```
error: expected ‘;’ before numeric constant
#define SMARTVER_HELPER_(x) 00 ## x
                            ^
```

Is there an enhanced code to do this ?

Comment: `in C++` So why tag C? C is not C++. `at compile-time (Preprocessing)` And in C++ there may be no need to use preprocessing. You want to have that done _specifically_ with preprocessor __or__ in C++ at compile-time?

Comment: LibFmt might be able to do this, I know it has some constexpr support, not sure if it can handle this case

Comment: Can you describe what kind of functionality you need? Depending of that detail it is possible (or not) to solve your problem using `constexpr`, which is more clear then using macros.

Comment: C++ has lots of compile time capabilities. Valid use cases or macros are extremely rare nowadays. Please pick one language. If using the preprocessor is a strict requirement then it doesn't matter that much, but thats a weird requirement

Comment: I think this error can be solved by `#define SMARTVER_HELPER_(x) ## 00 ## x`. but this is not a good solution as others said

Comment: You really need to specify which language the question is about, and if you are looking for a compile-time generated _string literal_ or just compile-time generated code.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I know the difference between C/C++, but the desired output is highly applicable to both related languages. I need it to be at compile-time. I've changed the question to not hold 'preprocessing' anymore.

Comment: @JVApen By a quick eye, Its binary seems to be added to the binary I have, It's not desired as I'm working with embedded devices.

Comment: @MarekR  I need to number my devices at production as unique friendly sequenced names (not chip-id or MAC-Address). These names are used to communicate with each device separately.

Comment: @علیسالمی Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very ugly but this should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define VERSION 6

#if (version < 10)
    #define DEVICE_NAME "MyDevice000" STR(VERSION)
#elif (version < 100)
    #define DEVICE_NAME "MyDevice00" STR(VERSION)
#elif (version < 1000)
    #define DEVICE_NAME "MyDevice0" STR(VERSION)
#else
    #define DEVICE_NAME "MyDevice" STR(VERSION)
#endif

int main(void)
{
    puts(DEVICE_NAME);
}
```

Comment: that could be generalized with some ternary operators, even like `#define DEVICE_NAME ( version<10 ? "MyDevice000"STR(VERSION) : version<100 ? "MyDevice00" STR(VERSION) : etc.`. I could see even like `#define PAD_ZEROS(str)  ( sizeof(str) < 3 ? "00"str : sizeof(str) < 4 ? "0"STR : etc.`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for pointing that out, but  can you please show how? AFAIK you can not use `sizeof` with the preprocessor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079267/1606345, or you mean at runtime?, it seems that OP wants this to work at compile time.

Comment: Yes, that would be evaluated at runtime, still optimized by compiler. https://godbolt.org/z/cbGTxh it depends on the use case anyway.

Comment: Thanks, It worked well. Just edit the `version` to match the defined one. You consider it ugly, What would you think the 'neat' way would use ?

Comment: @HamzaHajeir It depends, if you are on c++, as pointed out by others, I will use `const_expr`, if you need a C/C++ solution, there are not many alternatives :(

Comment: It's C++, I've no good knowledge about `constexpr`. Can you share a good starting reference ?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to return a string from a `const_expr`, let me ask my minions tomorrow, stay tuned ...

Comment: @HamzaHajeir does this helps? https://godbolt.org/z/PqWzrh

Comment: Thanks , It worked well, but other compilers (as cpp.sh) gives this error `12:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr auto get_version()' not a return-statement`. It's the same of what my compiler gives.

Comment: It requires c++14 or more ... it seems that you are compiling with c++11

Comment: Under c++11 you can use https://godbolt.org/z/TT7GWE but notice that get_version() here is not solved at compile time (but at runtime)

Comment: I see, It's ok if it's solved at the very beginning of the run-time.

Comment: Oh, in such case you can use https://godbolt.org/z/PnfEzY and avoid the `static` var

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225071/discussion-between-david-ranieri-and-hamza-hajeir).