# convert digital to string in macro

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a preprocessor token to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string)

```
#define num 1234
```

I want to define a "const char*" based on num, in the sample it would be:

```
#define num_str "1234"
```

Can I write a macro statement to achieve this? 
NB: 1234 would be changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but the macro substitution can get a little strange-looking. The double-macro substitution is there for a reason, and if you think about it for awhile, it will become clear why it is needed.

```
#define STRINGIZER_(exp)   #exp
#define STRINGIZER(exp)    STRINGIZER_(exp)
#define NUM 1234

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *p = STRINGIZER(NUM);
    printf("%s\n",p);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running this:

```
1234
```

The reason for the double substitution: At first glance one may think this will solve the problem:

```
#define STRINGIZER(exp)    #exp
#define NUM 1234

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *p = STRINGIZER(NUM);
    printf("%s\n",p);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this produces:

```
NUM
```

which is not what we're trying to do. If you want the actual expansion of the NUM macro first then that is what you have to do: force the expansion. By forcing the preprocessor to substitute *first* through an intermediate expansion (as I show at the top of this answer) the passed-in macro is expanded first, *then* string-ized.

**Side Bar:** This technique is particularly useful for generating wide-char versions of predefined preprocessor macros that otherwise hold regular strings. For example, the `__FILE__` macro. Suppose you wanted a wide-char version of this (a string prepended with 'L') You may first think this will work:

```
#define WIDESTR(str)    L##str
```

but expanding this with `__FILE__` as in:

```
const wchar *p = WIDESTR(__FILE__);
```

will result in a compiler error: `"Undefined identifier: L__FILE__"`

So how can we address this? The same way we did above.

```
#define WIDESTR_(str)       L##str
#define WIDESTR(str)        WIDESTR_(str)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const wchar_t* p = WIDESTR(__FILE__);
    wcout << p << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On my system, this produces:

```
/Users/craig/tmp/main/main/test.cpp
```

**In Closing...**

As a consolation prize, we combine everything in this answer into one giant goo-pile, what do we suppose happens when we do *this*:

```
int main()
{
    const wchar_t *p = WIDESTR(STRINGIZE(NUM));
    wcout << p << endl;
    return EXIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You slipped into C++ in the middle.

Comment: @luserdroog yeah, I noticed. I think it was because I was too lazy to go find the wide-version of printf. I should probably fix that.

Comment: Ah, well. +1 anyway. Nice illustration of the *why* of the double-expansion.

Answer (score 0):

How will the string be used in the rest of your code? Does it have to be a string macro? The standard way to create strings from other values is using sprintf() from string.h

```
#define num 1234
sprintf(string,"%d",num);
```

Comment: Yes, it should be a macro. Just for a test, thank you.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for catching the typo "%s" instead of "%d". Since a macro is required the stringize answer would be my suggestion as well.