# C preprocessor insert/append token in string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I have the following macro:

```
#define ASSERT_ITERATOR_VALUE_TYPE(Iterator__, Value_type__)                      \
static_assert(std::is_same<Value_type__, typename Iterator__::value_type>::value, \
              "Expected iterator with value type #Value_type__")
```

In the macro above I'm trying to insert/append the `Value_type__` token in the string literal that's feed in as the second input argument in `static_assert`.

Obviously, this is not what I'm trying to achieve, since if I state the macro as:

```
ASSERT_ITERATOR_VALUE_TYPE(std::set<int>::iterator, double);
```

I'll get the message:

```
error: static assertion failed: Expected iterator with value type #Value_type__
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where instead I would like to take the message:

```
error: static assertion failed: Expected iterator with value type double
                                                                  ^^^^^^
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/697a7c37f2ae8fb0)

### Q

Is there some kind of preprocessor sorcery that will help me achieve what I wan't?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string

Comment: Don't spam, tags! This is not C!

Comment: @Olaf C is pretty much C++. Plus the preprocessor comes from C.

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." Jesus Christ... Going back to work...

Comment: @101010: Please provide a reference to the C standard where it allows templates, inheritance, user-namespaces, etc. And to the C++ standard where it allows VLAs, FAMs, etc. Until then: please refrain from spreading such nonsense. And I did not remove the preprocessor tag. The C tag is nonsense, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define ASSERT_ITERATOR_VALUE_TYPE(Iterator__, Value_type__)                      \
static_assert(std::is_same<Value_type__, typename Iterator__::value_type>::value, \
              "Expected iterator with value type " #Value_type__)
```

You expand the macro parameter into a string literal, and then rely on string literal concatenation.