# How can I pass a string as a preprocessor token?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, compiler-flags

I am trying to pass a string as a parameter when compiling to this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define MY_STRING #STRING_IN

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << MY_STRING;
}
```

It is compiled with the flag:

```
-DSTRING_IN=foo
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> error: stray '#' in program
>
>  #define MY_STRING #STRING_IN
>
>                    ^
>
> note: in expansion of macro 'MY_STRING'
>
>      std::cout << MY_STRING;
>
>                   ^~~~~~~~~
>
> [...]
>
> Compiler returned: 1
> ```

See also [here](https://godbolt.org/g/ajECnM).

How can I pass a parameter via [`-D...`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) and then turn that into a string?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I tried many combinations before posting here, just not the correct one...
It works when I stringify the token like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define MY_STRING TOSTRING(STRING_IN)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << MY_STRING;
}
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string) for the more general case.

Comment: There's a redundant layer

Comment: @PasserBy i'd be glad to see a idomatic solution, because this is just the hack i came up with after giving up to really understand what is going on ;)

Comment: I meant, you could get rid of the `TOSTRING` layer

Comment: @PasserBy No, that's not redundant. Macro arguments are not expanded when used with `#`. An additional layer is needed if you do want them expanded.

Comment: @PasserBy this works, but my trouble started when combining this with passing the token via `-D..`

Comment: @PasserBy Did you actually check the preprocessed result? That evaluates `*"a"`, not `*"b"`.