# Printing out a Variable from Compiler options

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a very simple C program:

```
# program test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD \"%s\"\n\n", FOO);
}
```

and compiled with

```
gcc -o prog -D FOO=bar test.c
```

Basically what I am looking to have the following output:

```
HELLO WORLD "bar"
```

When I attempt to compile the above, I get the error

```
<command line>:1:13: note: expanded from here
#define FOO bar
```

I'm even going so far as to do the following (and yes, I know this is not good):

```
#indef FOO
    define ZZZ sprintf("%s", FOO)
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

`#define FOO bar` makes no sense in your example; what is the bare word `bar`?

If you want to replace it with the string `"bar"`, then you need to produce

```
#define FOO "bar"
```

You can achieve this by adding quotes to your CLI flag, which typically should be escaped:

```
gcc test.c -D FOO=\"bar\" -o prog
./prog
HELLO WORLD "bar"
```

Comment: Ugh, it's embarrassing when the answer is THIS simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: bar != "bar". So it is not something OP wants

Comment: @Paul but you asked something completely different.

Comment: Example when your method will be useless https://godbolt.org/z/5Pb58qr68. Usually definitions passed to the compiler have some meaning. And `bar` cannot be replaced by `"bar"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to stringify it.

```
#define STR(x) XSTR(x)
#define XSTR(x) #x


#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD \"%s\"\n\n", STR(FOO));
}
```

output:

```
HELLO WORLD "bar"
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cqd9GP5zb

Two macros have to be used as we need to expand the macro first and then stringify it.

Comment: Not your downvote, but if you believe this is the correct solution, with the other answer being incorrect, why not vote to close this topic as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240353/2505965)?