# Using C preprocessor to construct a string literal for scanf?

Tags: c, string, concatenation, scanf, c-preprocessor

I'm attempting to create an `sscanf` string literal to aid in buffer overrun prevention in C99. The goal is something like:

```
#define MAX_ARG_LEN   16

char arg[MAX_ARG_LEN] = "";

if (sscanf(arg, "%"(MAX_ARG_LEN-1)"X", &input) > 0)
```

The obvious "manual" solution is something like:

```
#define MAX_ARG_LEN   16
#define MAX_ARG_CHARS "15"

char arg[MAX_ARG_LEN] = "";

if (sscanf(arg, "%"MAX_ARG_CHARS"X", &input) > 0)
```

However, I would prefer something to automatically generate "%15X" given a buffer size of 16.  This link is *almost* works for my application: [Convert a preprocessor token to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string) but it does not handle the -1.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Kernighan and Pike discuss this issue in their (excellent) book '[The Practice of Programming](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/)' and concluded that the most reliable and portable way to do this is to use `sprintf()` to generate the format string.

What you could do is define the macro as the length excluding terminal null, and then use that like this:

```
#define STR_EVALUATE(x)   #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)      STR_EVALUATE(x)
#define MAX_ARG_LEN 15
char arg[MAX_ARG_LEN+1] = "";

if (sscanf(arg, "%" STRINGIFY(MAX_ARG_LEN) "X", &input) > 0)
    ...
```

Or you could define MAX_ARG_STRLEN as 15 and MAX_ARG_LEN as MAX_ARG_STRLEN+1 and work accordingly.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, a longish explanation of why `STRINGIFY()` needs to be done the way Jonathan did it (with a layer of indirection):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798221/c-macros-to-create-strings/798311#798311

Comment: There's also the parallel discussion for token pasting (`##`) at [SO 1489932](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/).

Comment: The +1 implementation above is a perfectly good solution - thanks!