# scanf() variable length specifier

Tags: c, scanf

How can I use a variable to specify the max number of chars `scanf()` should read in?

For example using `printf()` you can use the * like so

```
#define MAXVAL 5
printf("Print at maximum MAXVAL chars: %.*s\n", MAXVAL, "myStringHere");
```

This will only print 5 chars, how can I make `scanf` only read in MAXVAL? MAXVAL must be used as the length specifier. I **cannot** simply do

```
scanf("%5s", string);
```

Right now I can only think of reading into a large array using `scanf` then using `ssprintf` to store the string into my length limited string. Using a length specifier would be so much easier however.

Comment: Size  reduce of `-1` that amount because `scanf` add a NUL character reading for that string(`%s`). E.g. `scanf("%4s", string);`

Comment: @user3121023 I think he wants to use `MAXVAL` instead of hardcoding a value in the format string.

Comment: @mafso `fgets` breaks on newlines, `scanf` breaks on whitespace. @CSStudent you can create format specifier in code.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves You are correct, I need to use `MAXVAL`

Comment: @clcto "scanf breaks on whitespace" ignores the effect of the format parameter.  The function `scanf()` does not necessarily break on white-space as it depends on the format.  `scanf("%5s")` will consume leading white-space (not break on w-s), then scan non-white-space characters until 1) white-space (does break on w-s) 2) 5 `char` read 3) EOF or 4) IOError.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C preprocessor to construct a string literal for scanf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740039/using-c-preprocessor-to-construct-a-string-literal-for-scanf)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the C preprocessor to help you with that.

```
#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(X) STR2(X)
scanf("%" STR(MAXVAL) "s", string);
```

The processor combines `"%" STR(MAXVAL) "s"` to `"%5s"`

Comment: Thats quite a clever method. Interesting use of the preprocessor

Comment: I've just tried this method, whats the need in using 2 `#defines`? Can't I just use `#define STR(x) #x` and then use `scanf("%" STR(MAXVAL) "s", string);` ?

Comment: @CSStudent, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/c-stringify-how-does-it-work.

Comment: After reading through the answers to that question I'm still confused. I don't see why 2 `defines` are needed. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you don't use two levels, `"%" STR(MAXVAL) "s"` will be transformed to `%MAXVALs`, not `%5s`.

Comment: It seemed to have worked using gcc with only one define, to test I used: `#define STR(x) #x #define MAX 50` and `printf("one define: %%" STR(MAX) "s");` and it output `one define: %50s`  I used `%%` so the % char would be printed to stdout.

Comment: I don't know how you are getting the above output. Checkout this example at http://ideone.com/aaw2bD.

Comment: @CSStudent: The two definitions are necessary so that the argument is expanded properly.  That is, if `STR(X)` was simply defined as `#x`, then `STR(MAXVAL)` would expand to `#MAXVAL`, meaning the `scanf` call would expand to `scanf("%" "MAXVAL" "s", string );`, which is not what you want.  By using the second define, `MAXVAL` will expand to 5 before being stringized.

Comment: @JohnBode Cheers John once again

Comment: The same approach (but perhaps with better macro names was used in the answer to a very similar question from 2010: [Using C preprocessor to construct a string literal for scanf?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2740039/1281433)

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 5
#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)

int main(void){
    char string[MAXLEN+1];

    scanf("%" S(MAXLEN) "s", string);
    printf("<%.*s>\n", MAXLEN, string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Kernighan and Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Practice_of_Programming) recommend using snprintf() to create the format string.
I developed this idea into a method that safely reads strings:

```
void scan_string(char *buffer, unsigned length) {
    char format[16]; // Max int (10) + %, s & null-terminator (3)
                     // Rounded up to the closes power of 2
    snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", length - 1);
    scanf(format, buffer);
}

int main() {
  char str[5];
  scan_string(str, sizeof(string));
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the format string be null-terminated, hence the size being 12+1?

Comment: @sspathare97, you are right. Was a long time ago. Updated the length and improved some of the comments as well.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and update!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You need to use something other than `scanf()`. A good and popular choice is `fgets()`, although its semantics are slightly different: `fgets()` will read a line of input, whereas `scanf()` with `%s` will read whitespace separated sequences of characters.

To use `fgets()`, you'd want something like:

```
fgets(string, MAXVAL, stdin);
```

If for some reason you really want to use `scanf()`, have a look at this question: [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Comment: This is probably the best option to maintain good readability but I think I will go with the preprocessor trickery. So I can still use `scanf()`