# C Void ending issue

Tags: c, void

I am trying to write a simple parking arrangement code, I want to sort the capacity by 1000 vehicles, color, license plate and model

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void NewCar()
{
    char model[1000][20];
    char color [1000][20];
    char number[1000][20];
    int x = 1;
        printf("\nModel: ");
        scanf("%s",model[x]);
        printf("Color: ");
        scanf("%s",color[x]);
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf("%s",number[x]);
}
void CarList()
{
    int x;
    char model[1000][20];
    char color [1000][20];
    char number[1000][20];
    for (x ; x >= 1 ; x--)
    {
        printf("\n%d. Car: %s %s %s",x,number[x],model[x],color[x]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char model[1000][20];
    char color [1000][20];
    char number[1000][20];
    char menu;
    int x = 1;
    flag:
    printf("New Car(N)\nCar List(L)\n");
    scanf("%s",&menu);
    if (menu == "n" || menu == "N")
    {
        NewCar();
        goto flag;
    }
    if (menu == "l" || menu == "L")
    {
        CarList();
        goto flag;
    }
}
```

[image: Code Output]

when i don't use void, the code works but i have to use void

Example of the output I want;

```
 1. Car Red Jeep FGX9425
 2. Car Yellow Truck OKT2637
 3. Car Green Sedan ADG4567
 ....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use void", exactly? And what doesn't work? And in what way? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Please don't use `goto` as a substitute for a loop. It's a really bad idea

Comment: @UnholySheep It's not _that_ bad. In this particular case (a state machine) it may even be clearest.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&menu);` is very wrong as `menu` is a single `char` and thus cannot store any string except the empty one. Probably meant to use `%c` instead.

Comment: There's a lot of issues in this code unrelated to `void`,  e.g.: `scanf("%s",&menu);` is wrong, as `menu` is a single `char` and `if (menu == "n" || menu == "N")` is not how you compare strings in C (you'd use `strcmp` for that)

Comment: @UnholySheep there is nothing wrong with using goto as long as you use it correctly.

Comment: You're using "parallel" arrays (e.g. `color`, `model`, and `number`) that are all indexed by the same thing. This "cries out" for a `struct`: (e.g.) `struct car { char color[20]; char model[20]; char number[20]; }; struct car carlist[1000];`You are repeating these arrays at _function_ scope, so changes in one will _never_ be seen by another function (e.g. `CarList` will never see changes to the values in `main`). Better is: `void CarList(struct car *list,int carcount) { ... }` and have `main` do: `CarList(&carlist,carcount);` where `carcount` is the # of active/valid elements in `carlist`

Comment: @CraigEstey can you write what you say into the code ?

Comment: [Always] compile with `-Wall -O2` to get warnings and _fix_ those warnings/errors.

Comment: thank you to everyone for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

*Never* use `goto`. Use (e.g.) a `while` loop.

Your `scanf` for `menu` would [probably] overflow.

As others have mentioned, a number of bugs.

I've refactored your code with your old code and some new code. This still needs more error checking and can be generalized a bit more, but, I've tested it for basic functionality:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// description of a car
struct car {
    char model[20];
    char color[20];
    char number[20];
};

int
NewCar(struct car *cars,int carcount)
{
    struct car *car = &cars[carcount];

    printf("\nModel: ");
    scanf("%s", car->model);

    printf("\nColor: ");
    scanf("%s", car->color);

    printf("\nNumber: ");
    scanf("%s", car->number);

    ++carcount;

    return carcount;
}

void
CarList(struct car *cars,int carcount)
{
    struct car *car;
    int caridx;

    for (caridx = 0;  caridx < carcount;  ++caridx) {
        car = &cars[caridx];
        printf("%d. Car: %s %s %s\n",
            caridx + 1, car->number, car->model, car->color);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
#if 1
    int carcount = 0;
    struct car carlist[1000];
#endif
#if 0
    char menu;
    int x = 1;
#else
    char menu[20];
#endif

    // force out prompts
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    while (1) {
        printf("New Car(N)\nCar List(L)\n");
#if 0
        scanf("%s", &menu);
#else
        scanf(" %s", menu);
#endif

        // stop program
        if ((menu[0] == 'q') || (menu[0] == 'Q'))
            break;

        switch (menu[0]) {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            carcount = NewCar(carlist,carcount);
            break;

        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            CarList(carlist,carcount);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> As you said, there are a few minor errors, it's not a problem for me, but I can write errors if you want to know and fix them.(if you write the plate with a space between it, the code repeats the "new car car list" command many times)

Okay, I've produced an enhanced version that replaces the `scanf` with a function `askfor` that uses `fgets`. The latter will prevent [accidental] buffer overflow. And, mixing `scanf` *and* `fgets` can be problematic. Personally, I always "roll my own" using `fgets` as it can provide finer grain control [if used with wrapper functions, such as the `askfor` provided here]

**Edit:** Per chux, I've replaced the `strlen` for removing newline with a safer version that uses `strchr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRMAX      20

// description of a car
struct car {
    char model[STRMAX];
    char color[STRMAX];
    char number[STRMAX];
};

// askfor -- ask user for something
void
askfor(const char *tag,char *ptr)
{

    printf("Enter %s: ",tag);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(ptr,STRMAX,stdin);

    // point to last char in buffer
    // remove newline
#if 0
    ptr += strlen(ptr);
    --ptr;
    if (*ptr == '\n')
        *ptr = 0;
#else
    // remove trailing newline [if it exists]
    ptr = strchr(ptr,'\n');
    if (ptr != NULL)
        *ptr = 0;
#endif
}

int
NewCar(struct car *cars,int carcount)
{
    struct car *car = &cars[carcount];

    askfor("Model",car->model);
    askfor("Color",car->color);
    askfor("Number",car->number);

    ++carcount;

    return carcount;
}

void
CarList(struct car *cars,int carcount)
{
    struct car *car;
    int caridx;

    for (caridx = 0;  caridx < carcount;  ++caridx) {
        car = &cars[caridx];
        printf("%d. Car: %s %s %s\n",
            caridx + 1, car->number, car->model, car->color);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int carcount = 0;
    struct car carlist[1000];
    char menu[STRMAX];

    // force out prompts
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    while (1) {
        askfor("\nNew Car(N)\nCar List(L)",menu);

        // stop program
        if ((menu[0] == 'q') || (menu[0] == 'Q'))
            break;

        switch (menu[0]) {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            carcount = NewCar(carlist,carcount);
            break;

        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            CarList(carlist,carcount);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Thank you for your bug fix, but as I said in my question, I have to do the "New car" feature using void. You did it with `int`, can you do it with `void`?

Okay. When you said "using void", what you meant wasn't totally clear to me [or some others]. There were enough bugs that they overshadowed some other considerations.

So, I have to assume that "using void" means that the functions return `void`.

Your original functions were defined as `void NewCar()` and `void CarList()`. Those could not have done the job as is, so they had to be changed.

If you have similar criteria, a better way to phrase that would be:

> I must create two functions, with the following function signatures ...

Anyway, here's the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRMAX      20

// description of a car
struct car {
    char model[STRMAX];
    char color[STRMAX];
    char number[STRMAX];
};

// askfor -- ask user for something
void
askfor(const char *tag,char *ptr)
{

    printf("Enter %s: ",tag);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(ptr,STRMAX,stdin);

    // remove trailing newline [if it exists]
    ptr = strchr(ptr,'\n');
    if (ptr != NULL)
        *ptr = 0;
}

void
NewCar(struct car *cars,int *countptr)
{
    int carcount = *countptr;
    struct car *car = &cars[carcount];

    askfor("Model",car->model);
    askfor("Color",car->color);
    askfor("Number",car->number);

    carcount += 1;
    *countptr = carcount;
}

void
CarList(struct car *cars,int carcount)
{
    struct car *car;
    int caridx;

    for (caridx = 0;  caridx < carcount;  ++caridx) {
        car = &cars[caridx];
        printf("%d. Car: %s %s %s\n",
            caridx + 1, car->number, car->model, car->color);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int carcount = 0;
    struct car carlist[1000];
    char menu[STRMAX];

    // force out prompts
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    while (1) {
        askfor("\nNew Car(N)\nCar List(L)",menu);

        // stop program
        if ((menu[0] == 'q') || (menu[0] == 'Q'))
            break;

        switch (menu[0]) {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
#if 0
            carcount = NewCar(carlist,carcount);
#else
            NewCar(carlist,&carcount);
#endif
            break;

        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            CarList(carlist,carcount);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, given your original functions, it may be possible that the signatures *have* to be: `void NewCar(void)` and `void CarList(void)` and that the car list variables must be *global* scope.

This would be a less flexible and desirable way to do things, but here is a version that uses only global variables for the lists:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRMAX      20

// description of a car
struct car {
    char model[STRMAX];
    char color[STRMAX];
    char number[STRMAX];
};

#if 1
int carcount = 0;
struct car carlist[1000];
#endif

// askfor -- ask user for something
void
askfor(const char *tag,char *ptr)
{

    printf("Enter %s: ",tag);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(ptr,STRMAX,stdin);

    // remove trailing newline [if it exists]
    ptr = strchr(ptr,'\n');
    if (ptr != NULL)
        *ptr = 0;
}

void
NewCar(void)
{
    struct car *car = &carlist[carcount];

    askfor("Model",car->model);
    askfor("Color",car->color);
    askfor("Number",car->number);

    carcount += 1;
}

void
CarList(void)
{
    struct car *car;
    int caridx;

    for (caridx = 0;  caridx < carcount;  ++caridx) {
        car = &carlist[caridx];
        printf("%d. Car: %s %s %s\n",
            caridx + 1, car->number, car->model, car->color);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
#if 0
    int carcount = 0;
    struct car carlist[1000];
#endif
    char menu[STRMAX];

    // force out prompts
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    while (1) {
        askfor("\nNew Car(N)\nCar List(L)",menu);

        // stop program
        if ((menu[0] == 'q') || (menu[0] == 'Q'))
            break;

        switch (menu[0]) {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
#if 0
            carcount = NewCar(carlist,carcount);
#else
            NewCar();
#endif
            break;

        case 'l':
        case 'L':
#if 0
            CarList(carlist,carcount);
#else
            CarList();
#endif
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I marked it as the correct answer

Comment: You're welcome. You can also "upvote" it as a "good" answer (and can upvote other answer that may come it). Good luck. BTW, a `struct` is _very_ powerful, so it's worth some study.

Comment: As you said, there are a few minor errors, it's not a problem for me, but I can write errors if you want to know and fix them.(if you write the plate with a space between it, the code repeats the "new car car list" command many times)

Comment: `scanf(" %s", menu);` is as good a [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Recommend a width limit. ``scanf("%19s", menu);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Did a 2nd code example that replaces `scanf` with `fgets`, both for preventing buffer overflow and getting whole line strings. I'm not as much of a fan of `scanf("%19s",menu)` and I tried something similar to `int max = 19; printf("%*s\n",max,menu);` for `scanf`: `int max = sizeof(menu) - 1; scanf("%*s",max,menu);` but it didn't work. Is there such an equivalent for `scanf`? I'm looking for something other than: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410690/scanf-variable-length-specifier or use of the `m` specifier [as it does an extra/hidden `malloc`]

Comment: Is there such an equivalent for scanf? ---> No - sadly.  `m` is not part of the standard C lib.  Could use `#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a
#define STRLEN_MAX 19
  char menu[STRLEN_MAX + 1];
  scanf("%" xstr(STRLEN_MAX) "s", menu);`, but `fgets()` is better.

Comment: Minor: `ptr += strlen(ptr);
    --ptr;
    if (*ptr == '\n')
        *ptr = 0;` is UB with nefarious input and `*ptr== '\0';`  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2410359) and others.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica _Sigh_, yes. I fixed it. Don't know what I was [non-]thinking as I mostly use `strchr` [vs. `strlen`] for newline stripping in my own code, for the reasons alluded to ...

Comment: Nit -- "*never use*" `goto` -- except to jump out of nested loops, etc.. It's not a blanket *never*. It does have it's uses. GNU libc would fall apart without it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The [linux] kernel uses `goto` [probably] more than `glibc`. I used `goto` for the same purpose [_four_ decades ago ;-)]. Better a hard rule for a _newbie_ [with the bad habit of using `goto` instead of loop]. IMO, `goto` is an _advanced_ technique. But, even though _slightly_  slower, instead of `while (1) { ... while (1) { ... if (stop_on_expr) goto stopme; ... }} stopme:`, I use a control variable: `int more = 1; while (more) { ... while (more) { ... if (stop_on_expr) { more = 0; break; } } }`

Comment: @craigestey Thank you for your bug fix, but as I said in my question, I have to do the "New car" feature using void. You did it with int, can you do it with void?