# Bubble sort returning multiple identical results

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, bubble-sort

This is a follow up from a previous post I made earlier trying to get the values from a file. I modified it a bit and pre-define my sorting arrays, so everything is "sort" of working. The name sort is working in a sense, but when I output the result, I get the same result 2-3 times and not showing all of the data correctly.

I removed the Struct as it was just causing me problems and stuck with normal uncontrolled arrays.

```
    // Sort by Name method
    sortByName(hurricanYear, name, state);

    // Output results to screen
    printf("\nName Sort\n\n");
    printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Year", "Name", " State");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
        printf("%-10d%-10s%-10s\n", hurricanYear[i], name[i], state[i]);


/* This function sorts the strings by Name, while
   maintaining stability with its respected data */
void sortByName(int year[], char* name[], char* state[])
{
    int i, n;

    // Loop for row count
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
    {
        // Loops for element count in name array
        for (n = 0; n < i; n++)
        {
            // If name takes precedence over n+1 in array 
            // Copy name string to array
            if (strcmp(name[n], name[n + 1])>0)
            {
                char* pName = name[n];
                strcpy(name[n], name[n + 1]);
                strcpy(name[n + 1], pName);

                // Sort year according to name
                int t = year[n];
                year[n] = year[n + 1];
                year[n + 1] = t;

                // Sort state according to name                
                char* pState = state[n];
                strcpy(state[n], state[n + 1]);
                strcpy(state[n + 1], pState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is what I was expecting but off with the name sort function.

Name Sort

```
Year      Name       State
1972      Agnes      FL
1969      Agnes      FL
1960      Agnes      FL
1983      Alicia     TX
1992      Andrew     FL-LA
1989      Andrew     FL-LA
2004      Charley    FL-SC-NC
1999      Charley    FL-SC-NC
1995      Charley    FL-SC-NC
2003      Charley    FL-SC-NC
2005      Dennis     FL-AL
2004      Dennis     FL-AL
2004      Dennis     FL-AL
2004      Dennis     FL-AL
2009      Ida        MS
2005      Ida        MS
2005      Ida        MS
2008      Ida        MS
2011      Irene      NC-NJ-MA-VT
2012      Isaac      LA
```

Is it my for loop doing this, or am I obtaining strcpy() results more than once in my function? This is also the list I used:

```
1960 Donna Fl-NC
1969 Camille MS
1972 Agnes FL
1983 Alicia TX
1989 Hugo SC-NC
1992 Andrew FL-LA
1995 Opal FL-AL
1999 Floyd NC
2003 Isabel NC-VA
2004 Charley FL-SC-NC
2004 Frances FL
2004 Ivan AL
2004 Jeanne FL
2005 Dennis FL-AL
2005 Katrina FL-LA-MS
2005 Rita TX-LA
2008 Wilma FL
2009 Ida MS
2011 Irene NC-NJ-MA-VT
2012 Isaac LA
```

Comment: I believe your bug is here: `char* pState = state[n];` note that you are just copying a pointer not the data it points to. So after `strcpy(state[n], state[n + 1]);` both `pState` and `state[n]` contain the same state which is what was in `state[n + 1])`

Comment: Would you please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I see your code is not complete.

Comment: _Side note:_ You're using "parallel" arrays (multiple arrays indexed by the same variable) instead of a single array of `struct`. See my [very] recent answer, where another OP had the same construct, and I provided a way to refactor it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179379/5382650

Answer (score 0):

Ty Drescherjm for pointing that out. I managed to fix it by removing the pointer and replacing it with a strcpy()

```
#define MAX 100
void sortByName(int year[], char* name[], char* state[])
{
    int i, n;
    char plh[MAX]; // placeholder

    // Loop for row count
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
    {
        // Loops for element count in name array
        for (n = 0; n < i; n++)
        {
            // If name takes precedence over n+1 in array 
            // Copy name string to array
            if (strcmp(name[n], name[n + 1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(plh, name[n]);
                strcpy(name[n], name[n + 1]);
                strcpy(name[n + 1], plh);

                // Sort year according to name
                int t = year[n];
                year[n] = year[n + 1];
                year[n + 1] = t;

                // Sort state according to name                
                strcpy(plh, state[n]);
                strcpy(state[n], state[n + 1]);
                strcpy(state[n + 1], plh);
            }
        }
    }
}
```