# C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro

Tags: c-preprocessor, stringification

I want to stringify the result of a macro expansion.

I've tried with the following:

```
#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define TEST thisisatest
#define TESTE QUOTE(TEST)
```

And TESTE gets expanded to: "TEST", while I'm trying to get "thisisatest". I know this is the correct behavior of the preprocessor but can anyone help me with a way to achieve the other one?

```
Using TESTE #TEST is not valid
Using TESTE QUOTE(thisisatest) is not what I'm trying to do
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798221/c-macros-to-create-strings

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str) QUOTE(str)
#define TEST thisisatest
#define TESTE EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST)

int main() {
    printf(TESTE);
}
```

The reason is that when macro arguments are substituted into the macro body, they are expanded *unless* they appear with the # or ## preprocessor operators in that macro. So, `str` (with value `TEST` in your code) isn't expanded in `QUOTE`, but it is expanded in `EXPAND_AND_QUOTE`.

Comment: #define PE(BZL,YY) printf("ERROR - " #BZL ": result: 0x%08x!", YY); Doing:int variable1=1; PE(Test1,variable1); --> Results printing: ERROR - Test1: result: 0x1!

Answer (score 18):

To clarify a bit more, essentially the preprocessor was made to execute another "stage". i.e :

1st case:

```
->TESTE
->QUOTE(TEST) # preprocessor encounters QUOTE 
 # first so it expands it *without expanding its argument* 
 # as the '#' symbol is used
->TEST
```

2nd case:

```
->TESTE
->EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST)
->QUOTE(thisisatest) 
  # after expanding EXPAND_AND_QUOTE
  # in the previous line
  # the preprocessor checked for more macros
  # to expand, it found TEST and expanded it
  # to 'thisisatest'
->thisisatest
```