# How to cause macro expansion before concatenation?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

```
#define JNI_DECLARE( classname, methodname ) \
     classname  ## methodname( JNI* env ) 

#define JAVA_CLASS Java_com_example
void JNI_DECLARE( JAVA_CLASS, open ) {}
```

This expands to:

```
void JAVA_CLASS_open( JNI* env ) {}
```

How do I get:

```
void Java_com_example_open( JNI* env ) {}
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#define JNI_DECLARE_INNER( classname, methodname ) \
     classname  ## _ ## methodname( JNI* env )
#define JNI_DECLARE( classname, methodname ) \
     JNI_DECLARE_INNER(classname, methodname)
```

see more here: [C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)

Comment: As a side note, I pretty confident that the IAR EWARM 6.4 compiler does the wrong thing. I ran this same code in IAR EWARM and gcc, and gcc did what I expected and IAR didn't.

Comment: hmm.. you can use gcc for the preprocessor phase