# C preprocessor stringification weirdness

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I am defining a macro that evaluates to a constant string, holding the filename and the line number, for logging purposes.

It works fine, but I just can't figure out why 2 additional macros are needed - `STRINGIFY` and `TOSTRING`, when intuition suggests simply `__FILE__ ":" #__LINE__`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define THIS_ORIGIN (__FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__))

int main (void) {
  /* correctly prints "test.c:9" */
  printf("%s", THIS_ORIGIN);
  return 0;
}
```

This just seems like an ugly hack to me.

Can someone explain in detail what happens stage by stage so that `__LINE__` is stringified correctly, and why neither of `__FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(__LINE__)` and `__FILE__ ":" #__LINE__` works?

Comment: [You might find these answers helpful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)

Comment: The C++ FAQ has an item on this, and even says "Try concatenating a symbol with __LINE__ and see what happens then.": http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the order of expansion. The [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html) says:

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, unless they are stringified or pasted with other tokens. After substitution, the entire macro body, including the substituted arguments, is scanned again for macros to be expanded. The result is that the arguments are scanned twice to expand macro calls in them.

So if the argument will be stringified, it is not expanded first. You are getting the literal text in the parenthesis. But if it's being passed to another macro, it is expanded. Therefore if you want to expand it, you need two levels of macros.

This is done because there are cases where you do **not** want to expand the argument before stringification, most common being the `assert()` macro. If you write:

```
assert(MIN(width, height) >= 240);
```

you want the message to be:

```
Assertion MIN(width, height) >= 240 failed
```

and not some insane thing the MIN macro expands to (in gcc it uses several gcc-specific extensions and is quite long IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply use `__FILE__":"#__LINE__` because the stringify operator `#` can only be applied to a macro parameter.

`__FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(__LINE__)` would work OK with other text (eg  `__FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(foo)`, but doesn't work when used with another macro (which is all `__LINE__` really is) as the parameter; otherwise that macro doesn't get substituted.

Comment: Yes, but you don't really explain *why* it doesn't work with another macro.

Comment: Because that's the rule. There's really nothing more to it.

Comment: But *what* is the rule and *why* does it exist...? (yes, there is a very good reason for it).