# C/C++ macro evaluation order

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)

Shortly:

```
#include <iostream>

float pi(){ return 3.14; }

#define PRINT(x) std::cout << #x << std::endl;

#define PI pi()

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PRINT(PI)
    PRINT(pi())
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
PI
pi()
```

Is there any way to get only preprocessed data in macro argument? To get as a result

```
pi()
pi()
```

?

EDIT:

I haven't noticed this question: [C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)
Duplicate...

Comment: @j_kubik, you can close your own question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another helper macro:

```
#define QU(x) #x
#define PRINT(x) std::cout << QU(x) << std::endl;
#define PI pi()
```