# How to initialise a C string with a 16-bit integer?

Tags: c, string, initialization

I want to create a global 22 character (+ NULL) string in C. I am initialising it like this:

```
#define SVN_REVISION     "1143"
#define SERIAL_NUMBER    "PST3201109270001"
char general_info[23] = SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER SAMPLING_FREQUENCY;
```

So far, this works fine. general_info is initialised with the concatenation of the two strings. Now, for the last two characters, I want them to be a 16-bit integer. But I can't simply do this:

```
#define SVN_REVISION          "1143"
#define SERIAL_NUMBER         "PST3201109270001"
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY    (UINT16)500
char general_info[23] = SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER SAMPLING_FREQUENCY SAMPLING_FREQUENCY;
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to embed 16-bit integer `500` as binary data in the end of the string, you can use raw hex bytes:

```
/* Little-endian unsigned 16-bit integer with the value 500 */
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY    "\xf4\x01"
```

Beware, though, endianness is architecture dependent, so you might want to add an extra macro to correctly order the bytes depending on the architecture:

```
#ifdef ... /* little endian */
#define BYTES2(a,b) b a
#else ... /* big endian */
#define BYTES2(a,b) a b
#endif
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY    BYTES16("x01", "\xf4")
```

**EDIT:** If you want to have a human-readable number, you can't have it at compile-time (at least not in C), but you can initialize it at runtime:

```
#define SVN_REVISION     "1143"
#define SERIAL_NUMBER    "PST3201109270001"
#pragma pack(push, 1)
union {
    struct {
        char svn_rev_serial[20];
        uint16_t freq;
        char nul;
    };
    char general_info[23];
} u = {{
    SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER,
    500,
    '\0'
}};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

This uses more non-standard (but well-supported) constructs, like `#pragma pack` and writing to one union member and reading from another.

Comment: @themel, well, if it already dictates fixed-size binary data, *surely* it will not assume NULL-terminated strings...

Comment: But now SAMPLING_FREQUENCY is not human readable, except in the comment. Is there some way to convert 500 into "\xf4\x01'" using the preprocessor?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet not that I can think of at compile time.

Comment: This is the best answer. However, I have decided to do it at run time, and use a union so that it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the usual "stringify operator" trick.

```
#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(str) #str
#define STRINGIFY(str) STRINGIFY_HELPER(str)

#define SVN_REVISION          "1143"
#define SERIAL_NUMBER         "PST3201109270001"
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY    (UINT16)500
char general_info[23] = SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER SAMPLING_FREQUENCY STRINGIFY(SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);
```

You need the double macro to exploit the preprocessor `#` operator because the macro arguments are not expanded when the `#` operator is used. Thus, an extra macro step is needed to first expand the arguments, and then use the `#` operator. A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro/5965760#5965760).

---

***edit***

Actually, that won't work because of the `(UINT16)` cast, that will be stringified as well. You can still get away with macros only if you can afford creating an extra macro:

```
#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(str) #str
#define STRINGIFY(str) STRINGIFY_HELPER(str)

#define SVN_REVISION          "1143"
#define SERIAL_NUMBER         "PST3201109270001"
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_NOCAST    500
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY    (UINT16)(SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_NOCAST)
char general_info[23] = SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER SAMPLING_FREQUENCY STRINGIFY(SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_NOCAST);
```

It isn't very elegant, but you still avoid the problem of duplicating the `500` value (you just have to update it in a single place and everything will work fine).

Comment: Won't work - the `(UINT16)` will be lexically visible in the string

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this:

```
char general_info[23] = SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER SAMPLING_FREQUENCY;
strcat(genral_info, itoa(SAMPLING_FREQUENCY));
```

Comment: I'd suggest `snprintf` (+ `assert`) instead of `strcat` for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Youy can try something like :

```
#define SVN_REVISION          "1143"
#define SERIAL_NUMBER         "PST3201109270001"
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY    "\xF4\x1\00\00"
char general_info[29] = SVN_REVISION SERIAL_NUMBER SAMPLING_FREQUENCY SAMPLING_FREQUENCY;
```

\xF4\x1\00\00 is the memory representation for decimal 500 (at least on Windows platforms)