# Can I load my #define into an NSString?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)

I have this define:

```
#define VERSION 0.3.2
```

I want to convert this to `@"0.3.2"` (an NSString) -- is it possible? Presume that I am not allowed to add quotation marks to the #define.

Something like this, but presumably with an extra step:

```
NSString *myVersion = [NSString stringWith???:VERSION];
```

Comment: There's a way to do it, but it takes some macro magic that I always have to Google for.

Comment: I agree with @robmayoff -- my Q is a dup. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Does the version number you're #defining happen to be the version number of your application (the one in your XCode Target settings)?  If so, you can retrieve it programmatically using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]`.  This returns a string.  To compare two version number strings, call `[versionString1 compare:versionString2 options:NSNumericSearch]`.  If you're storing some other version number, disregard.

Comment: Our authoritative version is in a define, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

As in the possible dup I linked, you need two more levels of macros because you want to stringify a macro expansion:

```
#define VERSION 0.3.2
#define StringifyWithoutExpandingMacros(x) #x
#define Stringify(x) StringifyWithoutExpandingMacros(x)

NSLog(@"VERSION = %@", @StringifyWithoutExpandingMacros(VERSION));
// output: VERSION = VERSION

NSLog(@"VERSION = %@", @Stringify(VERSION));
// output: VERSION = 0.3.2
```

Note that you can just stick an `@` in front of the macro invocation.  It doesn't need to be inside the macro.  You can put it in the macro if you want, though:

```
#define NSStringifyWithoutExpandingMacros(x) @#x
#define NSStringify(x) NSStringifyWithoutExpandingMacros(x)

NSLog(@"VERSION = %@", NSStringify(VERSION));
// output: VERSION = 0.3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

[Stringify](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/file_and_line_error_string.htm)!

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define AT __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__)
```

@HotLick's Macro magic at it's finest.