# C nested macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why in one case nested macros works while in the other does not?

Case 1:

```
#define name(val) #val
#define name2(front, back) name(front ## back)
...

printf("%s\n", name2(foo, bar));   // foobar
```

Case 2:

```
#define paste(front, back) front ## back
#define name(val) #val
#define name2(front, back) name(paste(front, back))
...


printf("%s\n", name2(foo, bar));   // paste(foo, bar)
```

Comment: Did you look inside the preprocessed form, e.g. as obtained by `gcc -C -E` on Linux, of your source program (to which you could add "intermediate" code like `printf("%s\n", name(goo))`?

Comment: This link is helpful for me when learning http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the arguments to a macro aren't expanded if they appear along with a `#` or `##` in the macro body (as is the case with `val` in `name`). See the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro).

So in your second case you'll need to add an intermediate step to ensure that the argument is expanded. E.g. something like:

```
#define paste(front, back) front ## back
#define name(val) #val
#define expand(val) name(val)  // expand val before stringifying it
#define name2(front, back) expand(paste(front, back))
```