# C++ namespace as a macro value

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces, stringification

I have simple delegate functions in my C++ test code. Since I cannot include the original implementation .cpp files(embedded ones), I use delegate .cpp file in the tests that are running on PC. My idea is to simply use the same macro as a body for the implementation, except the parentheses () and arguments which will supplied according to the signature.

I tried something like:

```
void Flash::init()
{
   DELEGATE_DESTINATION();
}

bool Flash::write(args)
{
   DELEGATE_DESTINATION(args);
}

bool Flash::read(args)
{
   DELEGATE_DESTINATION(args);
}
```

Where

```
void Flash::init()
bool Flash::write(args)
bool Flash::read(args)
```

Are identical to the ones in the embedded project implementation ones. In the test files I simply relay the call to the fake implementations. One possible solution would be to already include the signature and implementation in the fake classes not using relaying, I know.

I am having hard time figuring out the macro. I tried something like:

```
#define FAKE_PREFIX             fakes::device::Flash::
#define DELEGATE_DESTINATION    FAKE_PREFIX##__FUNCTION__
```

Which expands to **FAKE_PREFIX__FUNCTION__**

Well then after going through [C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)
I can get only **fakes** expanding in place.

My goal would be to have a result like

```
fakes::device::Flash::init
```

and so on for **read** and **write**.

Comment: You could use inline namespaces

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot could you give me an example what you have in mind. I checked it out tried it out, but could not get any concise results... Thanks.

Comment: I like to, but unfortunately my experience with inline namespace is limited. I just know that are here to "default" a nested namespace to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be done far simpler. You don't need the full power of the pre-processor:

1. You don't concatenate tokens (`::` is not part of a valid token). You just need to print one macro next to another.
2. `_FUNCTION_` isn't a pre-processor macro, it's a string literal ([in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Function-Names.html) and other compilers).

So to do what you want, you need to pass the function name into your macro:

```
#define FAKE_PREFIX fakes::device::Flash::
#define DELEGATE_DESTINATION(func)  FAKE_PREFIX func
```

Then you define your functions, like this:

```
bool Flash::write(args)
{
  DELEGATE_DESTINATION(write)(args);
}
```

It's all live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37832d98870c8104).

Comment: I still get `Use of undeclared identifier 'FAKE_PREFIX__FUNCTION__'`