# C Preprocessor + and = usage

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to recreate this line via the preprocessor

```
#pragma location = ADDR + OFFSET
```

Currently, i'm pretty close by using this ([C Preprocessor, Stringify the result of a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro)):

```
#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str) QUOTE(str)
#define TEST(X) location  =  ## X ##   + OFFSET
#define TESTE(X) EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST(X))

_Pragma(TESTE(ADDR));
```

Which works if i remove the = and + sign from

> #define TEST(x) location  =  ## X ##   + OFFSET

Unfortunately, adding the = or + sign provides me with these errors:

```
test.c:3:27: error: pasting "=" and "ADDR" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define TEST(X) location  =  ## X ##   + OFFSET
                           ^
test.c:4:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘TEST’
 #define TESTE(X) EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST(X))
                                   ^~~~
test.c:6:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘TESTE’
 _Pragma(TESTE(ADDR));
         ^~~~~
test.c:6:15: error: pasting "ADDR" and "+" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 _Pragma(TESTE(ADDR));
               ^
test.c:3:33: note: in definition of macro ‘TEST’
 #define TEST(X) location  =  ## X ##   + OFFSET
                                 ^
test.c:6:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘TESTE’
 _Pragma(TESTE(ADDR));
         ^~~~~
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to use token pasting in your macro definition? Just define it as `#define TEST(X) location  =  (X) + OFFSET` (note the parentheses for proper grouping in the event that `X` is an expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `##` operator:

```
#define QUOTE(str)  #str
#define TESTE(X)    QUOTE(location = X + OFFSET)

_Pragma(TESTE(ADDR));
```

[Example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/byAwXA)