# Using macros that define version numbers in the form 10.0.0

Tags: c++, c, macros, version

I compile one of my C codes with a Mathematica C header file. Mathematica uses a macro to tell you which version you are using. The format is

```
#define WSMATHVERSION 10.0.0
```

I'm more familiar with this pattern of version numbering in macros,

```
//  BOOST_VERSION % 100 is the patch level
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 is the minor version
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100000 is the major version

#define BOOST_VERSION 103900
```

I like this because it is easier to check whether the version number is greater than a particular version. Is there a canonical way to use the Mathematica style? I find `too many decimal points in number` type errors etc. I'm using C but C++ only solutions may be interesting too.

Comment: Is this c or c++, please clarify he answers might be different.

Comment: the only way you can make the contents of that value legal C syntax is to [stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro) it.

Comment: @KamiKaze C; see edited Q

Comment: Might be better to ask this at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Lundin not sure, it's about C preprocessor macros rather than mathematica language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, preprocessor conditions can only be composed of integers. So, it's unfortunatly impossible to write a preprocessor condition with the WSMATHVERSION macro.