# Expand macros inside quoted string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c-strings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Macros to create strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798221/c-macros-to-create-strings)

I have a function which accepts one argument of type `char*`, like `f("string");` 
If the string argument is defined by-the-fly in the function call, how can macros be expanded within the string body?

For example:

```
#define COLOR #00ff00
f("abc COLOR");
```

would be equivalent to

```
f("abc #00ff00");
```

but instead the expansion is not performed, and the function receives literally `abc COLOR`.

In particular, I need to expand the macro to exactly `\"#00ff00\"`, so that this quoted token is concatenated with the rest of the string argument passed to `f()`, quotes included; that is, the preprocessor has to finish his job and welcome the compiler transforming the code from `f("abc COLOR");` to `f("abc \"#00ff00\"");`

Comment: The preprocessor does not touch string literals.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798221/c-macros-to-create-strings

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't expand macros in strings, but you can write

```
#define COLOR "#00ff00"

f("abc "COLOR);
```

Remember that this concatenation is done by the C preprocessor, and is only a feature to concatenate plain strings, not variables or so.

Comment: Is this equivalent to passing 2 arguments to f() ?

Comment: @davide no, putting two string literals next to each other makes the C compiler concatenate them.

Comment: No, the strings will be concat by the compiler. At compile time, the string will result in "abc #00ff00"

Comment: I believe the concatenation `"abc ""#00ff00"` to `"abc #00ff00"`is performed by compiler instead of preprocessor.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html
Notice in the second paragraph: `The preprocessor will replace the stringified arguments with string constants. The C compiler will then combine all the adjacent string constants into one long string.`

Answer (score 4):

```
#define COLOR "#00ff00"
f("abc "COLOR);
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this works because C "automatically concatenates" two strings if they appear without anything in between.