# warning: unknown conversion type character ‘T’ in format [-Wformat]

Tags: c, gcc, types, format, c-preprocessor

That's the code:

```
#define TAM_NOME_PRODUTO 50
[...]
struct produto
{
char nome_produto[50+1];
[...]
};
typedef struct produto Produto;
[...]
Produto *novo;
novo=malloc(sizeof(Produto));
[...]
scanf("%TAM_NOME_PRODUTO[^\n]", novo->nome_produto);
[...]
```

gcc accuses on the line of the scanf:

> produto.c:61:3: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘T’ in format [-Wformat]
>   produto.c:61:3: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

I think the define is not working as it should. How fix the code to make it work?

Comment: Macros are not expanded within strings like that. Have a look at [Expand macros inside quoted string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12958925/1281433).  In turn, that's closed as a duplicate of [C Macros to create strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/798221/1281433).

Comment: Based on the answer I linked to above, and @BLUEPIXY's comment, you could write (with some additional defines) `scanf("%" STR(TAM_NOME_PRODUTO) "[^\n]", novo->nome_produto);`.

Comment: Also see the very related (maybe a better duplicate) [Using C preprocessor to construct a string literal for scanf?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2740039/1281433)

Answer (score 0):

In [scanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html), the percent (%) symbol has special meaning and expects to be followed by a formatting character that matches the corresponding type. Although you are trying to use "%50", this is a string literal and thus the macro name is just an ordinary string in this context. In order to expand it, you will need to use implicit concatenation of adjacent string literals and use the string tokenizing symbol `#`.

Comment: Downvote was a misclick, but this *isn't* all that helpful.  OP's code begins with `#define TAM_NOME_PRODUTO 50`, and the last sentence in the Q is "I think the define is not work as i would, how fix the code to make it work?".  The intent was to expand the macro inside a string (which doesn't work, of course).

Comment: No, using the number i did through the define limits the number of characters to be read, asnd using [^\n] I make the scanf read spaces. On other part of the program I put the \0 on the string.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, it was only when you wrote your comment that I realized  that he is referencing "TAM_NOME_PRODUTO" (or trying to reference it) in the string... the naming threw me off a bit... it seemed like the macro wasn't referenced and irrelevant.