# Cannot resolve function-like macro inside conditional compilation block

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, define-syntax

Consider the following - I want to check with `#if` `#endif` whether a 
token is defined somewhere in the code.
I am using a `CONCAT(input)` macro that should glue the constant and changing parts of the token that I want to check.

Unfortunately, the approach presented below causes a compilation error:

`error: missing binary operator before token "("`

---

I have found the expressions that can be put inside a `#if` `#endif` block:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If

And apparently it states that:

*Macros. All macros in the expression are expanded before actual computation of the expression’s value begins.*

It turns out that `(CONCAT(test))` should be resolved, but it is not.

Is there any workaround allowing to resolve concatenated token names correctly in a conditional compilation block?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONCAT(input) string##input
#define stringtest 1

int main(void) 
{
    #if defined(CONCAT(test)) && (CONCAT(test)==1)
        printf("OK");
    #else
        printf("NOT");
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use just: `#if CONCAT(test) == 1` it will work and is enought.
The statement `#if defined(CONCAT(test))` does **not** work because `CONCAT(test)` will be evaluated to `stringtest` which will be evaluated to `1`, and you can't use `defined` on a numerical constant.

> A different situation came to my mind - what if I want to check whether the token is eg. != 1 Then if it is not defined anywhere, the condition will evaluate to true. So there would be no difference between token not defined and token being different than 1.

You could handle `== 0` **equal** `to not defined`. So you could use: `#if CONCAT(test) != 0 && CONCAT(test) != 1` where `CONCAT(test) != 0` means `defined(CONCAT(test))`. That is the only alternative, because you can't get macro expansion work in a `#ifdef` or `#if defined()` statement, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703516/how-do-you-perform-macro-expansion-within-ifdef) which is very similar to yours.

---

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_4.html) says:

> Conditionals written like this:
>       `#if defined BUFSIZE && BUFSIZE >= 1024`
>
> can generally be simplified to just `#if BUFSIZE >= 1024`, since if `BUFSIZE` is not defined, it will be interpreted as having the value zero.

Also it can be helpful if you check macro expansion by using `gcc -E yourSource.cpp`.

gcc --help:

> -E Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link

Comment: Thank you for the simpler suggestion. A different situation came to my mind - what if I want to check whether the token is eg. `!= 1` Then if it is not defined anywhere, the condition will evaluate to true. So there would be no difference between token not defined and token being different than 1. Do you have any suggestion for such a case?

Comment: I edited my answer to meet your additional question, I hope that helps as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Only literals can be used.

You should check for macro directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONCAT(input) string##input
#define stringtest 1

int main(void) {
    #if stringtest  == 1
        printf("OK");
    #else
        printf("NOT");
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Since you don't need defined check, you can use like this:

```
#define CONCAT(input) string##input
#define stringtest 1

int main(void) {
    #if CONCAT(test) == 1
        printf("OK");
    #else
        printf("NOT");
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, this is superfluous. `#if stringtest  == 1` is enough.