# C99 Macro to build a quoted string literal after evaluation

Tags: string, macros, c99, literals, expansion

I'm developing an embedded application in C99, and the project contains some integer constants defined like:

```
#define LEVEL1     0x0000
#define LEVEL2     (LEVEL1 + 1)
```

It has since become useful to keep track of these values for logging purposes, so I would like to use a macro to create a string literal from the *evaluated* versions of the above.  For example:

```
strncpy(str, STRING(LEVEL2), len);
```

would ideally evaluate to

```
strncpy(str, "0x0001", len);
```

or even

```
strncpy(str, "0001", len);
```

Using a two-stage macro with the # operator (as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195975/how-to-make-a-char-string-from-a-c-macros-value)) almost works.  It evaluates to

```
strncpy(str, "(LEVEL1 + 1)", len);
```

I would like to avoid the use of a run-time function - hence my attempt at a macro solution.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the pre-processor stringizer is a massive pain, you need to add a level of indirection both when creating version numbers and when stringizing:

```
#define STRING1(s) #s
#define STRING(s) STRING1(s)

#define LEVEL(x) x
#define LEVEL1 LEVEL(1)
#define LEVEL2 LEVEL(2)

printf(STRING(LEVEL2));
//2
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because the preprocessor knows nothing about the C language so it cannot to evaluation.

I see two options to get the desired result:

#### Manual evaluation

Write your levels exactly as you want them to appear and use a single stringizer operator:

```
#define LEVEL1 0x0000
#define LEVEL2 0x0001
#define STRING(x)   # x

strncpy(str, STRING(LEVEL2), len);
```

A disadvantage is that this is error prone and might clash with local coding conventions.

#### Runtime evaluation

Use one of the string format functions `sprintf` or `snprintf`.

```
#define LEVEL1 0x0000
#define LEVEL2 0x0001

char level[7];
snprintf(level, sizeof level, "%#06x", LEVEL2);
strncpy(str, level, len);
```

This has the runtime overhead you wanted to avoid.