# How to make a -D value from cmd line become a string?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'm facing a tricky problem. I'd like to forge a **C** source file content according to compiler command line. For example(using VC):

If I use command line

```
cl -c -E -Dfoo=rice test.c
```

I wish to get **actual** **C** content (after preprocessing):

```
char *s = "rice";
```

If I use command line

```
cl -c -E -Dfoo=ball test.c
```

I wish to get actual **C** source file content:

```
char *s = "ball";
```

Now finding a solution...

FIRST TRY:

```
// test.c
#define STRNAME(n) #n
char *s = STRNAME(foo);
```

-- No luck. No matter what foo is defined to be on command line, I always get

```
char *s = "foo"; // Oh no!
```

SECOND TRY (closest I can image, but still verbose):

```
// test.c
#define STRNAME(n) #n
char *s = foo;
```

This time, I have to change my command line verbosely:

```
cl -c -E -Dfoo=STRNAME(rice) test.c
```

Now I get

```
 char *s = "rice";
```

Is there a way to help me out of this verbosity?

BY the way: I really do not like to introduce quotes into command arguments (make them become part of `argv[x]`, because you will not be able to write such command line reliably and portably on Windows CMD and Linux Bash -- I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a char string from a C macro's value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195975/how-to-make-a-char-string-from-a-c-macros-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an extra level of indirection in the preprocessor to expand your macro first. Something like:

```
#define STRNAME1(n) #n
#define STRNAME(n) STRNAME1(n)
char *s = STRNAME(foo);
```

This is a fairly common pattern, and results in your macro being expanded and *then* converted to a string, rather than just converted to a string.

Comment: Could someone pinpoint which statement in C99 spec clarify this behavior? The key point is **when does ``foo`` becomes ``ball``**  and **when does ``#bar`` becomes "bar"** . I checked C99 sections around 6.10.3.2, but find it very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try passing a quoted string to the `-D`? You should be able to do that by properly escaping the quotes:

```
-D'foo="rice"'
```

Comment: This works on Linux Bash, but not on Windows CMD. On CMD, if that is argv[1], its value will be `-D'foo=rice'` , strlen(argv[1]) is 12.