# C: Why is macro expansion not happening recursively?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a test program like below.

```
  #define TEST(A,B)  A
  #define TEST2(A,B) (A,B)
  #define TEST3(A,B) TEST TEST2(A,B)

  int main()
  {
     TEST3(Hello,World)  //This will expand to TEST (Hello,World)
     TEST (hello, World) // This will expand to hello
  }
```

The `TEST3` will expand to "`TEST (Hello,World)`", but it won't be expanded further using `TEST` definition. I initially thought it must be due to a space between `TEST` and `TEST2(hello, world)` in the `TEST3` definition. But the plain invocation of `TEST (hello, world)` expands properly. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word TEST in `#define TEST3(A,B) TEST TEST2(A,B)` is not a function-like macro invocation because it is not followed by an open parenthesis.  When the pre-processor is expanding `TEST3(Hello, World)`, it encounters TEST, finds it is not an invocation of a function-like macro, and outputs it as text; then it processes `TEST2(A, B)` and that is a macro invocation, so it outputs the corresponding text, which is `(Hello,World)`, and it continues the processing with the open parenthesis.  The TEST is gone, never to be preprocessed again.

See [C preprocessor and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489985/15168) for a full discussion of macro expansion with quotes from the standard.  You might find [How to make a char string from a C macro's value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196018/15168) of some help, too.

Comment: Why in the the case of direct invocation of TEST, it is being treated as function type macro even though there is a space between MACRO name and '('?

Comment: Because the (absence of) space only matters in the `#define TEST(A,B)` line, not in the invocation.

Comment: Slightly more detail: the first expansion of `TEST3(Hello,World)` is `TEST TEST2(Hello,World)`. The key point here is that the "first round" of expansion is solely replacing the arguments and any `#` or `##` operators -- NOT expanding any sub-macros.  Then preprocessing resumes as if the file now contained those tokens instead of the original; i.e. the final result of `TEST3(Hello,World) bla` is exactly the same as the final result of `TEST TEST2(Hello,World) bla`.  Now it is easy to see that `TEST` is processed and done with before we even start to expand `TEST2`.