# why Stringification not working as expected

Tags: c

I have C code that contains strinigication as below.

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define foo 4
```

Now xstr (foo) is evaluating as "4" correctly.

But str(foo) is getting evaluated as "foo". But I thought it should be evaluated as "4". Can any one please explain me how it is evaluated as "foo".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a char string from a C macro's value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195975/how-to-make-a-char-string-from-a-c-macros-value)

Comment: The correct reason : The problem is that when you have a macro replacement, the preprocessor will only expand the macros recursively if neither the stringizing operator # nor the token-pasting operator ## are applied to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of macro expansion rules in C. Using the `str(s)` you defined the `foo` immediately gets placed as `#foo` rather than evaluating the value of `foo`. When you wrap it with `xstr` it gives it a chance to actually evaluate `foo` before applying stringification.

The process looks something like this

```
str(foo)->#foo->"foo"
xstr(foo)->str(4)->#4->"4"
```

Comment: I got one correct explanation (shamelessly copied from one of the stack overflow questions): The problem is that when you have a macro replacement, the preprocessor will only expand the macros recursively if neither the stringizing operator # nor the token-pasting operator ## are applied to it.

Comment: Yeah. I understood your example. I shouldn't have told "correct" in my comment.