# Make token concatenation before stringification in C macro

Tags: c, macros

I have two C macros, the first one is basically concatenating two tokens

```
#define _PY_CLASS_NAME(name) Py##name
```

The second macro is stringifying input argument

```
#define STR(text) #text
```

Because of the way C preprocessor work when I try something like

```
STR(_PY_CLASS_NAME(name))
```

I actually get "_PY_CLASS_NAME(name)". 
So the question is, how to avoid it?

I tried something like

```
#define CONCAT(A, B) #A###B
```

and it works. But maybe it is a better way to do it?

Comment: Note that you should not create names that start with an underscore followed by either another underscore or a capital letter.  Such names are 'reserved for any use' by the implementation.  See [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3).

Comment: In the `#define CONCAT(A, B) #A###B` example, the preprocessor is entitled to complain that the `##` operator is not joining two identifiers.  The 'maximal munch' rule means that you have `#A ## #B` and `#B` is not an identifier.  You certainly shouldn't try using it.

Comment: See also [How to concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in `arg ## _ ## MACRO`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/) and [How to make a char string from a C macro's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195975/)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: Second won't work no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define _PY_CLASS_NAME(name) Py##name
#define STR(a) STR_(a)
#define STR_(a) #a
```

This solves the problem in a different way and also would clarify how it macro works. Reason is - when macro arguments are substituted in the macro body, they are expanded until they appear with the `#` or `##` pre-processor operators in that macro.

Now doing this `printf("%s\n",STR(_PY_CLASS_NAME(name)));` prints `Pyname`.

Edit: The second one you mentioned won't work. The compiler complains as mentioned, of absence of valid preprocessing token.