# Preprocessor directive to create keywords in C

Tags: c, compilation, macros, preprocessor

I want to create this...

```
int main(void) {
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //Not an important Code
  }
  return 0;
}
```

in a fancier way, to create crazy ideas!
Is it possible to rewrite it like this?

```
#define A f
#define B or

int main(void) {
  int i;

  AB(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //Not an important Code
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I need to know if it's possible to create instrctions like a simple *for* composed by diferent *#defines*

Comment: Forget it. Trying to make a lazy implemetation for keywords is a going nowhere and makes your invented code hard to read.

Comment: Avoid preprocessor magic; it makes code unreadable.  You can concatenate tokens in the replacement text of a macro with `##` — `#define C(a, b) a ## b` and then `C(A, B)` would more or less do what you want; you just have to evaluate the expressions before concatenating: `#define E(a) a` — `#define C(a, b) E(a) ## E(b)` and `C(A,B)`.  But that's repulsive, especially for a split keyword.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tryed your idea, and it doesn't work for me. Gcc responds with: pasting ")" and "E" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define C(a, b) E(a)##E(b)

Comment: OK; as you can tell, I didn't test it.  It's doable (the concatenation of tokens defined via macros); there are answers about how to do it (some written by me in times past).  It isn't a good idea — that's the take home.   (Working set of macros: `#define A f` —  `#define B or` —   `#define E(a, b) a ## b` —  `#define C(a, b) E(a, b)` —  `` —  `C(A,B)` — output, `for`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you please provide the link? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/how-to-concatenate-twice-with-the-c-preprocessor-and-expand-a-macro-as-in-arg; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195975/how-to-make-a-char-string-from-a-c-macros-value

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

making

```
#define A f
#define B or
#define C(x, y) x##y
#define D(x,y) C(x,y)
```

then

```
D(A, B)(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

will be rewritten as

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: I think you need object-like macros for A and B, not function-like macros — as shown in the question.