How to use while to sum power like 1+2²+3³
I'm trying to solve this problem without use pow().
I already do 1+2+3+4...+N, and 1+2²+3²..+N², but it looks impossible to solve exactly 1+2²+3³+4⁴...+NN
Can anybody help me?
Code Below:
int i = 1, sum = 0, n;
printf("Number: ", &n) 
while (i <= n) {
    sum = sum + i
    i = i + 1
}
printf("Sum is: ", sum)
//I can't do more


You need another, inner loop, to calculate i^i. BTW - using a for loop instead of while seems more natural here.

just write your own function intPow.

printf("Number: ", &n) - I think you wanted to use scanf (and you are missing %d). Also you're missing a ; in several places.

I recommend to use compilation flags: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror (on gcc/clang), or /W4 /WX (on msvc) to catch format string mistakes. You have some mistakes there.

This problem has a very limited range of input before it becomes intractable without a bignums library; might as well store it in a look-up table.

This code calculates the sum of 1+2²+3³+4⁴..., I put n=10 for simplicity
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int i = 1, j, n = 10;

        unsigned long long sum = 0;
        unsigned long long nextp;

        while (i <= n) {

                nextp = 1;
                j = 1;

                while (j <= i) {
                        nextp *= i;
                        j++;
                }

                sum += nextp;
                i++;
        }   

        printf("%llu\n", sum);

}


it is bad practice to have everything in main.

@MarekR indeed. I decided to do so for the sake of simplicity.

@sotona: you could have initialized "nextp" directly to "i" ;)

@MarekR: I understand your point for bigger programs. But I do not see the need for that rule for small / example programs. Will you please drop a short explanation?

@virolino This is more like teaching beginner a good practices. If you will show bad practices to beginner early, he will keep repeating them later since this will be more familiar to him. Once bad hobbit is learned, it is hard to fight with it.

@MarekR: Yes, I know what you mean. I also hate when I see coding guidelines which break all other rules when presenting an example for some rule. But in this particular case, I kind of have mixed feelings. Good explanation and good point though.

@MarekR: Also, yes, "bad hobbits" are the worst :))

@sotona: I am lazy to calculate, but if int is 32 bits, you might have some nice overflow for 10**10 (maybe even earlier). I forgot to write it earlier.

Here is the classic implementation:
unsigned int f(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1, s = 1; i <= n; ++i, sum += s, s = 1)
        for (unsigned int j = i, x = i; j > 0; j >>= 1, x *= x)
            if (j & 1) s *= x;
    return sum;
}

or
unsigned int f(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1, s = 1; i <= n; ++i, sum += s, s = 1)
        for (unsigned int j = i, x = i; j > 0; j /= 2, x *= x)
            if (j % 2) s *= x;
    return sum;
}

or expanded version:
unsigned int f(unsigned int n) {

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {

        unsigned int s = 1, x = i;

        for (unsigned int j = i; j > 0; j /= 2) {
            if (j % 2) s *= x;
            x *= x;
        }

        sum += s;
    }

    return sum;
}

A little explanation:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%u", f(5)); // 5^5 = 5^(1 + 4) = (5^1) * (5^4)
}


j & 1 is a shorthand (obfuscation?) of j % 2 == 0 and j >>= 1 is the same for j / 2?

@s_baldur, yes, i added this variant.

functions are very compact, but not very readable and not easy to debug.

@MarekR, thanks for the feedback, I added the expanded version.

Here a version that uses separate functions to make the code more modular.
It also uses for loops instead of while ones, since I find it more natural in this case.
n is hard coded to 3 as an example.
#include <stdio.h>

int IntPow(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<exp; ++i)
    {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}

int SumOfPows(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        sum += IntPow(i,i);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("sum: %d \n", SumOfPows(n));
}

Output:
sum: 32

Live demo 1
Note:
Instead of ints you can use larger integral types. They can also be unsigned (like uint64_t, assuming int is 32 bit) in case you need to support larger values.

I assumed that the purpose of this question is to get a solution using any kind of loop, and as I mentioned above I think for loops suit it best.
But if it must be while loop, here's a similar solution using only while:
#include <stdio.h>

int IntPow(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    int i=0;
    while (i<exp)
    {
        result *= base;
        ++i;
    }
    return result;
}

int SumOfPows(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i=1;
    while (i<=n)
    {
        sum += IntPow(i,i);
         ++i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("sum: %d \n", SumOfPows(n));
}

Output:
sum: 32

Live demo 2

fast power algorithm should be used: https://godbolt.org/z/7zxvK31P9

Thanks @MarekR. I am aware of such algorithms, but prefered to keep it a bit simpler as it seems a better fit for the level of the OP's question.

@wohlstad: the question is quite clear: How to use "while"... Your answer is for another question, I guess.

@virolino I am aware that the title mentions while, but in the body the OP only mentioned that they want to avoid pow. Anyway there was already a valid answer (by sotona) that demonstrates the usage of while. I thought that maybe an alternative using for (and a breakup to functions) might be helpful to the OP.

@virolino just in case I added a solution using only while loops (with a breakup into functions).

This example uses while loops, detects overflows and lets you check C types:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <locale.h>

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/196093/25547638
#define QUOTE(name) #name
#define STR(macro) QUOTE(macro)

// just to check uint16_t usage
#define def_use_uint16_for_accum 0

// sets the types used for N and for the accumulators
#if def_use_uint16_for_accum
    #define type_n uint16_t                             
    #define printf_format_type_n PRIu16                 
    #define type_accum_sum_power uint16_t               
    #define printf_format_type_accum_sum_power PRIu16   
#else

// set the type and the print format for N
    #define type_n uint16_t                             
    #define printf_format_type_n PRIu16                 

// set the type and the print format for accumulators
    #define type_accum_sum_power uint64_t               
    #define printf_format_type_accum_sum_power PRIu64   

// N.B.: N=20 is already too much event for uint64_t
#endif

// to print macro values as string
#define def_string_type_n STR(type_n)
#define def_string_type_accum_sum_power STR(type_accum_sum_power)

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // should show a dot as thousands separator in the printf
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");

    // set the N value
    const type_n N_final = 12;

    // splash
    printf("Calculating cumsum of %" printf_format_type_n "^%" printf_format_type_n "\n", N_final, N_final);
    printf("\tusing %s as type for N\n", def_string_type_n);
    printf("\tusing %s as type for accumulator of power\n", def_string_type_accum_sum_power);
    printf("\n");

    // accumulator for n^n values
    type_accum_sum_power cumsum_N_power_N = 0;
    // flag for error check
    unsigned int is_error  = 0;
    // loop summing n^n
    type_n n = 1;
    while(n <= N_final && !is_error)
    {
        // the accumulator for n*n*...n
        type_accum_sum_power accum_multiply = n;
        // loop accumulating the products n*n*... n
        type_n idx_multiply = 1;
        while(idx_multiply < n && !is_error)
        {
            // save previous accumulator value for overflow check
            type_accum_sum_power accum_old = accum_multiply ;
            accum_multiply  *= n;
            // overflow check
            if (accum_multiply  < accum_old)
            {
                is_error = 1;
                printf("***ERROR: overflow while calculating %" printf_format_type_n "^%" printf_format_type_n "\n", n, n);
                printf("\taccum now= %'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power "\n", accum_multiply);
                printf("\taccum previous= %'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power "\n", accum_old);
            }
            idx_multiply++;
        }

        // save previous accumulator value for overflow check
        type_accum_sum_power cumsum_N_power_N_old = cumsum_N_power_N;
        // add the new n^n just calculated
        cumsum_N_power_N += accum_multiply ;
        // overflow check
        if (cumsum_N_power_N < cumsum_N_power_N_old)
        {
            is_error = 1;
            printf("***ERROR: overflow while adding accumulator!\n");
            printf("\tn = %" printf_format_type_n "\n", n);
            printf("\taccum now= %'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power "\n", cumsum_N_power_N);
            printf("\taccum previous= %'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power "\n", cumsum_N_power_N_old);
        }
        // show current calculation
        if (!is_error)
        {
            printf("\t%" printf_format_type_n "^%" printf_format_type_n "=%'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power ", cumsum= %'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power "\n", n, n, accum_multiply, cumsum_N_power_N);
        }

        n++;
    }

    // error?
    if (is_error)
    {
        printf("Unable to do the math! :( \n");
    }
    // all OK?
    else
    {
        printf("OK: cumsum of %" printf_format_type_n "^%" printf_format_type_n " = %'" printf_format_type_accum_sum_power, N_final, N_final,  cumsum_N_power_N);
    }

}

Output for N_final=12:
Calculating cumsum of 12^12
    using uint16_t as type for N
    using uint64_t as type for accumulator of power

    1^1=1, cumsum= 1
    2^2=4, cumsum= 5
    3^3=27, cumsum= 32
    4^4=256, cumsum= 288
    5^5=3.125, cumsum= 3.413
    6^6=46.656, cumsum= 50.069
    7^7=823.543, cumsum= 873.612
    8^8=16.777.216, cumsum= 17.650.828
    9^9=387.420.489, cumsum= 405.071.317
    10^10=10.000.000.000, cumsum= 10.405.071.317
    11^11=285.311.670.611, cumsum= 295.716.741.928
    12^12=8.916.100.448.256, cumsum= 9.211.817.190.184
OK: cumsum of 12^12 = 9.211.817.190.184

Output for N_final = 20 (overflow is detected)
Calculating cumsum of 20^20
    using uint16_t as type for N
    using uint64_t as type for accumulator of power

    1^1=1, cumsum= 1
    2^2=4, cumsum= 5
    3^3=27, cumsum= 32
    4^4=256, cumsum= 288
    5^5=3.125, cumsum= 3.413
    6^6=46.656, cumsum= 50.069
    7^7=823.543, cumsum= 873.612
    8^8=16.777.216, cumsum= 17.650.828
    9^9=387.420.489, cumsum= 405.071.317
    10^10=10.000.000.000, cumsum= 10.405.071.317
    11^11=285.311.670.611, cumsum= 295.716.741.928
    12^12=8.916.100.448.256, cumsum= 9.211.817.190.184
    13^13=302.875.106.592.253, cumsum= 312.086.923.782.437
    14^14=11.112.006.825.558.016, cumsum= 11.424.093.749.340.453
    15^15=437.893.890.380.859.375, cumsum= 449.317.984.130.199.828
***ERROR: overflow while calculating 16^16
    accum now= 0
    accum previous= 1.152.921.504.606.846.976
Unable to do the math! :( 


I find this answer is overly complicated and the code contains too much boilerplate that's unnecessary/irrelevant to the question

The check for overflow isn't irrelevant IMHO; stated that the overflow depends upon the storage type, I think it was a good idea to let the user check with different types. If this was an assignment, and the overflow is not checked, it would be very easy to give an incorrect result even for low values of N.

The question was about how to solve this particular problem, and the asker expected an answer to this particular question. your code contains a lot of formatting, macro'd types etc. all things that aren't addressing the problem stated. The other answers are a lot more straight forward and easier to extract the solution from

The user apparently asked for a program, and not for an algorithm, then real data structures must be used, and all the annoying stuff related too; anyway I think you're right, I should have kept it simpler.

@michelesponchiado: I am aware that you used "cum" as short for "cummulative", but even then, I feel troubled. Just saying...

@michelesponchiado: the question is quite clear: How to use "while"... Your answer is for another question, I guess.

@virolino cumsum is an identifier commonly used, e.g. in Matlab; funny the first time, then you do not notice anymore.

The code is actively O&M hostile.   Aligned comments to the right of code are hard to read and extremely time-consuming to maintain when the code is modified.  Using typedef to hide common types such as uint64_t also makes maintenance much more difficult - for example, it makes it very hard to decide the proper way to handle any variable.  What's the proper printf() format specifier, for example.

I changed the code to use the while loops as per user request

@Andrew Henle many thanks for your reply! The typedef has been used to check the overflow Vs various data type selected; anyway the IDE typically shows you the macro expansion of simple typedefs, OK for the right aligned comments.

Abstracting away the pow part to avoid adding complexity to the loop:
#include <stdio.h>

int pow2(int x, int p) {
  // Caveat: this is very tractable but not the fastest algorithm
  if (p == 0) return 1;
  return x * pow2(x, p-1);
}

int main(void) {
  int i   = 1;
  int sum = 0;
  int n;
  // Beware: sum (as int) will overflow with big n
  puts("Enter your integer:"); 
  scanf("%d", &n);
  while (i <= n) {
    sum += pow2(i, i);
    i++;
  }
  printf("%d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}


We are supposed to divided the problem into two pieces.
The first is to get the exponent.Then you have a chance to make the exponent and the base together
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 3;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        int current=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(current!=0){
                current*=i;
            }
            if(current==0){
                current=i;
            }
        }
        sum = sum +current;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}


@Horoscope: the question is quite clear: How to use "while"... Your answer is for another question, I guess.
